# Typecast UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to UnsafeMutablePointer<#Struct type#>

Tags: swift

I created a struct in Swift called RGB, simple enough:

```
struct PixelRGB {
    var r: CUnsignedChar = 0
    var g: CUnsignedChar = 0
    var b: CUnsignedChar = 0

    init(red: CUnsignedChar, green: CUnsignedChar, blue: CUnsignedChar) {
        r = red
        g = green
        b = blue
    }
}
```

And I have a pointer `var imageData: UnsafeMutablePointer<PixelRGB>!`.

I wish to malloc some space for this pointer, but `malloc` returns `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` and I cannot cast it like below:

```
imageData = malloc(UInt(dataLength)) as UnsafeMutablePointer<PixelRGB> // 'Void' is not identical to `PixelRGB`
```

Anyway to solve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about `imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<PixelRGB>.alloc(dataLength)`?

Comment: @matt This should be an answer.

Comment: Okey-dokey, will do.

Comment: You would only malloc it if it needs to have a dynamic lifetime. Otherwise, why don't you just have a variable of type `PixelRGB`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think what you want to say is something like this:

```
imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<PixelRGB>.alloc(dataLength)
```

Comment: @AntonHolmquist imageData.destroy()

Comment: @AntonHolmquist The opposite of alloc() is dealloc(). The destroy() method is the counterpart of initialize().

Comment: This answer is a better way to solve the OPs problem, but it does not answer the question asked in the title.  Either the title should change, or someone should answer the question about type casting.

Comment: @Fooberman I'm not sure what you're after here, but feel free to supply your own answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
imageData = unsafeBitCast(malloc(UInt(dataLength)), UnsafeMutablePointer<PixelRGB>.self)
```

Ref: [Using Legacy C APIs with Swift](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift/)