# Swift - how to use malloc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, malloc

I'm trying to translate an Objective-C app into Swift and I don't know how to implement a malloc.

Is it possible to use it in Swift?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to use `malloc` for allocation some amount of memory, you don't need to do. Direct memory allocation isn't used in Swift.

Comment: @KyokookHwang: You *can* use malloc() without problems in Swift. The question is if you *should* do it or better use other data structures (e.g. Array).

Comment: It would help to see your concrete problem. malloc() can be used, but there might be better alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. My need is to allocate some memory for an audio buffer: buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 ); // buffer size

Comment: I will probably find another solution then. Thanks

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26006918/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a bridging header when you use ObjC or C from Swift. The functions exported by your bridging header are then available in your Swift app/module. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html), for the overview.

If you just need to "call some code" on the C-side, then the functions exported from C are basically just wrappers for Swift. However, if you need to interact with the data returned from those functions -- especially if malloc'd and not a simple primitive -- Swift has a number of C related types ready for your use (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_12) for specifics).

Furthermore, if you're trying to wrap or interact with C++ code, you *can't* directly do so from Swift. You have to setup an initial interface with ObjC or C for the C++ code, and then bridge that to Swift. Not really fun at all, but thankfully it's not as common a use case as bridging ObjC (primarily) or C.

... and for what it's worth, unless you need low level Core Audio for some reason (granted, like porting an app you already have), AVAudioEngine (iOS8+) is **so** much simpler for any applicable use case than Core Audio, and is readily available in Swift.

Comment: "…for any applicable use case." Well, almost any case. But there are things AVAudioEngine still can't do well enough, two years after this comment was made.