# Swift assign Double value to malloc'd array

Tags: ios, swift

I've been playing around with swift and encountered following issue:

```
var foo: Double = 5
var buffer = malloc(10)
buffer[0] = foo //Does not compile!
```

How can I assign an element in array a specific value?

Comment: Cast that memory to something useful, you can't assign numbers to `void *`. This isn't a Swift issue, it's a C issue.

Comment: What is the error message you received?

Comment: If you only need add this object to array: `var buffer = [foo]`

Comment: @CurlyCorvus, the error says `Expected Declaration`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are mixing C and swift,  malloc(10) does not give you a data type of Double, it gives you a type of void* I believe, which translates to unsafemutablepointer I believe if I remember correctly,  somebody please correct if wrong.

if you want a mutable array of doubles, then you need to do something like

```
var foo: Double = 5
var buffer = [Double]()
buffer.append(foo)
```

or

```
buffer.insert(foo, atIndex: 0)
```

If you want to stay with allocated memory, please see this answer about how to set it up properly:

[Swift - how to use malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996933/swift-how-to-use-malloc)

and do something like this:

```
var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(malloc(10))
```

or as user3441734 pointed out for a cleaner look

```
var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.alloc(1)
buffer.dealloc(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I wanted to keep the malloc in the answer, so I will include both

Comment: var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(malloc(10)) will not compile without import Foundation. .alloc() is 'pure' Swift and little bit safer. by the way, how much memory i need for 3 times  MyStruct? (maybe platform specific). using malloc is also discouraged by Apple

Comment: The answer link I provided explains how to use malloc, which tells you to import foundation, so redundancy in my answer is not needed,  and even though malloc is discouraged by Apple, the creator of the question is asking how to do it with malloc,  so an answer how to do it with malloc should also be provided for this post to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make an array of Double

```
var array = [Double](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0.0)
```

Then assign values to it:

```
array[9] = 1.23
```

Comment: The code you've given gives `fatal error: Array index out of range`.  You either need to allocate the array with a size, or use `.append()`.

Comment: for this to work, you need to do `var array = [Double](count: 10,repeatableValue 0)`

Comment: Interesting. I did a search for fixed-size array allocation in Swift and didn't find this. I'll change my answer.